# Two Identical tables in Oracle

Tags: oracle, toad

I have created two identical tables which list all the exceptions with regards to certain rules of products in the data base. table one is for week 1 table two is for week two the exception are just view on a weekly basis and no correction is made in the data base. week twos data includes the exceptions in week one i want to exclude week ones exceptions from week twos. only to view the new exceptions

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you add a timestamp to the tables and select/filter on this timestamp.

This way you also can put *all* exceptions into one table and just define two views.

I'm no good with PL/SQL, but maybe you can adapt my MySQL-sample:

```
CREATE DATABASE timetest;
CONNECT timetest;

CREATE TABLE errorlog (
  stamp TIMESTAMP NOT NULL ,
  error VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

INSERT into errorlog (`stamp`, `error`)
  VALUES (DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 8 DAY), 'old');
INSERT into errorlog (`stamp`, `error`)
  VALUES (NOW(), 'new');

SELECT * FROM errorlog WHERE stamp>DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY);
SELECT * FROM errorlog WHERE stamp<DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY);
DROP DATABASE timetest;
```

Gives me:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM errorlog WHERE stamp>DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY);
+---------------------+-------+
| stamp               | error |
+---------------------+-------+
| 2009-01-29 01:44:38 | new   |
+---------------------+-------+

mysql> SELECT * FROM errorlog WHERE stamp<DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY);
+---------------------+-------+
| stamp               | error |
+---------------------+-------+
| 2009-01-21 00:00:00 | old   |
+---------------------+-------+
```

Comment: i have a time stamp in both tables, the exceptions are not changed in the data base it is still pulls week1 data into week two data i thought that if i created 2 tables one with week 1 data and one with week two data i could then create a third table and some how remove week one from week two data?

Comment: if i do this as one table how would i remove the data for the first week that has already appeared on the report

Comment: I don't really understand your last question. By "select"ing only the data for timestamps in the last 7 days (first query) you do not have the data for the fiurst week in the result (only showing "new" values). To remove old entries, just "delete" where "stamp>DATE_...." as in the "select".

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has a MINUS operator so you can do

```
SELECT col_a, col_b... FROM table_new
MINUS
SELECT col_a, col_b... from table_old
```

That works as long as the columns have corresponding datatypes (so will work with SELECT * if the tables have identical structures).

Comment: hi trie the above is there anything else that you could suggest ?

Answer (score 0):

There also may be some advantage to breaking the table into partitions by year/week number.

Answer (score 0):

To really help you we need more information.  Are you talking about tables or views ("... the exception are just view on a weekly basis.. " part confused me)?

If you could provide a short complete example (yes - stolen from Tom Kyte) we could provide a complete answer.  That is if the above have not helped you.